# DISTINCT with HASH MATCH (Flow Distinct) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, distinct

Recently, while working in SQL Server, I got an interesting thing that removing `DISTINCT` keyword actually decreased my query performance and increased my search time.

I read that `DISTINCT` can make queries slow so I removed it to make them faster, but that made my query even slower.

Further experimenting, I got that when I add `DISTINCT`, SQL Server actually do something HASH MATCH (Flow Distinct) and this reduces the time, and even parallelism is added with HASH MATCH.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5000 
    [A].[Row Id], [A].[Account], ... other columns
FROM 
    [Archival System].[dbo].[Activity] A  
WHERE
    ([A].[Row Id] LIKE N'%{search_term}%' 
     OR [A].[Account] LIKE '%{search_term}%' 
     OR ... others conditions)
```

When I remove `DISTINCT` from this query, it becomes slower.

Here I have added TOP without ORDER BY as I a search string is not going to repeat again and if it occurs it would be rare. Hence I am avoiding ORDER BY to get a little more performance.

Below are my query execution plans with the query code of both my queries (previous and later) and the only change in query is just the `DISTINCT` keyword

Previous : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyV7FKiU9

Later: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1bFV9jUq

Can anybody tell me what this HASH MATCH (Flow Distinct) does, and why it just works when I add `distinct`?

And is it reliable to depend on that? As I am using `DISTINCT` now does it will continue to return results with the same time as it is returning now.

OR is there a better way to improve my query search time.

I am using SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically the big difference seems to be that the distinct (which requires either a sort or a hash) is deemed expensive enough to warrant parallelism, and you have enough cores that this makes the entire operation finish faster. Without the distinct, there is no need to sort, so it is just a single, serial scan. It still seems odd to me (because I think you asked a similar question recently) that you want 5000 rows but you don't care which ones (typically `TOP` is accompanied by an `ORDER BY` to be sensical).

Comment: Seems rather pointless to compare the plans since logically they are very different. As already noted, TOP without an ORDER BY clause is a logic fault and a simple examination of your query suggests you have data quality problems that will always impede the ability to get useful information efficiently. The idea of quickly retrieving some undefined subset of rows is an unusual goal generally. There are no techniques that can be applied universally to every query that will make them "faster". Short answer: no it is not reliable.

Comment: What do you see when you add `with(maxdop 1)` on both queries?